# How to pass multiple arguments to custom blade?

Tags: laravel-5

As the directive method only takes $expression, is there an example about how to pass multiple arguments, without using explode ?

I tried:

```
Blade::directive('reportLink', function($expression, $expression2) {
```

And then:

```
@reportLink("a", "b")
```

But I got error, missing argument 2..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came across this myself. Only way to do this is making it an array.

In your blade template:

```
@reportLink([$argument1, $argument1])
    --stuff--
@endreportLink
```

In your service provider:

```
Blade::directive('reportLink', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php App\ReportLink::YourMethod{$expression} ?>";
});
```

In your class:

```
class ReportLink
{
    public static function YourMethod($arguments)
    {
        dd($arguments); // this is now an array.
    }
}
```

Maybe you found this yourself already, but for future reference if people are searching for this.

Comment: *"for future reference if people are searching for this"* Like me! :-) I hope that at some point in the future Laravel will treat `$expression` as a proper variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma sepreted arguments like this

```
@reportLink($argument1, $argument1)
--stuff--
@endreportLink
```

You have to just explode the string at directive

```
Blade::directive('reportLink', function ($expression) {

    $expression = explode(',', $expression);

    return "<?php echo $expression[0].' '.$expression[1] ?>";
});
```

Comment: This may not work well if there are commas for any other reason.

Comment: @BrynnBateman, There is also one more problem with this solutoin, You will need to handle type convertions for numeric values.